# How to get original array from random shuffle of an array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was asked in an interview today below question. I gave O(nlgn) solution but I was asked to give O(n) solution. I could not come up with O(n) solution. Can you help?

```
An input array is given like [1,2,4] then every element of it is doubled and 
appended into the array. So the array now looks like [1,2,4,2,4,8].  How 
this array is randomly shuffled. One possible random arrangement is 
[4,8,2,1,2,4].  Now we are given this random shuffled array and we want to
 get original array [1,2,4] in O(n) time.

The original array can be returned in any order. How can I do it?
```

Comment: Can you post your existing solution? Also, Googling the question text [turns up what seems to be the original problem source](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-original-array-from-doubled-array/)

Comment: sort the array. take last element/2 and find it in array and store it in output and change the found element to -1.  Now take second last element/2 (if second last element is -1 then skip it)  and repeat same process.

Comment: @kcsquared but as per the problem that you have shared  O(nlogn) is a valid soln..

Comment: It is actually unfair that interviewers expect the candidate to improve the complexity within minutes whereas the interviewer actually took more than that in real life when he attempted it.

Comment: @nice_dev agreed (T_T)   ..In fact the interviewers don't even try/attempt the given problems before appearing in the interview. (they see straight answers/solutions) But I can say that this problem should be solved in 45 min interview. (It was not a difficult problem . when Interviewers want us to optimize space etc which is not good [generally they brag we have enough space don't worry next moment they want us to optimize space  XD] )

Comment: @adarsh Yes precisely. Even funnier is some people are getting frontend jobs after clearing such interviews. Clearly, no correlation between the two. It has become a reputation gesture these days for companies.

Comment: @nice_dev exactly ...

Comment: Are you looking for an implementation in a particular language, a proof of correctness and runtime, or an explanation of why a certain algorithm works? It's unclear what a 'reputable source' would be for an algorithms interview question.

Comment: @sachin note if your sorting solution is valid, if the input numbers are of maximum size (according to leetcode `0 <= changed[i] <= 10^5`) this means you can use radix sort to implement sorting in O(5n) = O(n). This is a trick worth knowing! It also means your solution satisfies the O(n) requirement, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Answer (score 3):

Here's an O(N) Java solution that could be improved by first making sure that the array is of the proper form. For example it shouldn't accept [0] as an input:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
  public static int[] findOriginalArray(int[] changed) {
    if (changed.length % 2 != 0)
        return new int[] {};

    // set Map size to optimal value to avoid rehashes
    Map<Integer,Integer> count = new HashMap<>(changed.length*100/75);
    int[] original = new int[changed.length/2];
    int pos = 0;

    // count frequency for each number
    for (int n : changed) {
        count.put(n, count.getOrDefault(n,0)+1);
    }

    // now decide which go into the answer
    for (int n : changed) {

       int smallest = n;
       for (int m=n; m > 0 && count.getOrDefault(m,0) > 0; m = m/2)  {
          //System.out.println(m);
          smallest = m;
          if (m % 2 != 0) break;
       }


       // trickle up from smallest to largest while count > 0
       
       for (int m=smallest, mm = 2*m; count.getOrDefault(mm,0) > 0; m = mm, mm=2*mm){

          int ct = count.getOrDefault(mm,0);
          while (count.get(m) > 0 && ct > 0) {
             //System.out.println("adding "+m);
             original[pos++] = m;
             count.put(mm, ct -1);
             count.put(m, count.get(m) - 1);
             ct = count.getOrDefault(mm,0);
          }

       }    
    }

    // check for incorrect format
    if (count.values().stream().anyMatch(x -> x > 0)) {
        return new int[] {};
    }

    return original;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] changed = {1,2,4,2,4,8};
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(changed));
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findOriginalArray(changed)));
  } 
}
```

But I've tried to keep it simple.

The output is NOT guaranteed to be sorted. If you want it sorted it's going to cost O(NlogN) inevitably unless you use a Radix sort or something similar (which would make it O(NlogE) where E is the max value of the numbers you're sorting and logE the number of bits needed).

### Runtime

This may not look that it is O(N) but you can see that it is because for every loop it will only find the lowest number in the chain ONCE, then trickle up the chain ONCE. Or said another way, in every iteration it will do O(X) iterations to process X elements. What will remain is O(N-X) elements. Therefore, even though there are for's inside for's it is still O(N).

An example execution can be seen with [64,32,16,8,4,2].
If this where not O(N) if you print out each value that it traverses to find the smallest you'd expect to see the values appear over and over again (for example N*(N+1)/2 times).

But instead you see them only once:

```
finding smallest 64
finding smallest 32
finding smallest 16
finding smallest 8
finding smallest 4
finding smallest 2
adding 2
adding 8
adding 32
```

If you're familiar with the Heapify algorithm you'll recognize the approach here.

Comment: This appears to give incorrect output for `[4,4,16,20,8,8,2,10]`, whose original array is `[2,4,8,10]`, while this outputs `[4,4,10]`

Comment: hmm.. the issue is that the solution requires a greedy traversal.. (going from lowest to highest) but that would require sorting (or at least partial sorting with a heap).

It works if you change it to a TreeMap and then iterate the keys rather than the original array.

Comment: I fixed it by checking the half value rather than the double.. that seems to do the trick

Comment: Hmm, it appears that it won't work on `[1,3,4,2,6,8]`, returning `[1,2]` instead of `[1,3,4]`. I don't believe any tiny changes can fix the idea fully without implementing something close to your 'greedy traversal'. That can be done in `O(n)`, without doing a Radix sort or anything similar. There's a Python implementation of the idea [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-original-array-from-doubled-array/discuss/1485450/Python-hashmap-O(n)-solution.-NO-Sorting!). Essentially, instead of just checking `n/2` as you do, you keep halving `n` until you find the smallest value in the chain.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. But yeah, by going down the chain it would work.
Radix is not truly O(N) though. So I don't think that's a valid solution either.

Comment: Hmm.. but walking down the chain seems to mirror the "percolate down" algorithm of Heapify. It may be possible that such an implementation is actually O(N) even though it appears to be O(NlogN). It would have to be proven. We do know that there is a limit to how deep the chain can be if it's a double array.

Comment: It looks like sift_down, but the structure is fairly different. I haven't written or read a full proof that it's `O(N)`, but I'm quite confident that it is, and that it wouldn't be hard to prove either. Once we see a number `x` in the main loop, we process all numbers reachable from x by dividing or multiplying by 2 any number of times- all their counts are 0 after the first time we see them.

Comment: Well if you max-heap heapify.. wouldn't it be possible to just "shift up" from the leaves of the heap? the leaves would be by definition the lowest values and the others the top values. So a reverse traversal eliminating the doubles would solve the problem.

1. Heapify (max-heap)
2. Traverse array from back to front. 
3. For each value, delete double value

Something like that

Comment: @AminM https://leetcode.com/problems/find-original-array-from-doubled-array/ try here please share your updated code using the concepts you told but it should follow O(n).

Comment: Ok. Fixed it using your suggestions (I think).
It passes leetcode tests now. And I'm convinced it's O(N) because of the explanation I gave.
There are some additional optimizations I also did but I leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: It is solved now

Comment: @AminM I think you misunderstood `An input array is given like [1,2,4] then every element of it is doubled and appended into the array.`. It doesn't say that the input array will always hold a geometric series with ratio 2, although the way you `trickle up from smallest to largest while count > 0` does assume so.

Comment: Upvoted, my earlier comments are now invalid, as this is a correct O(n) solution. I'm not extremely familiar with Java, but is setting the hashmap size manually that important? It reserves too much space anyways if the array has duplicates. Also, the innermost (triple nested) loop can be optimized away-- right now, if one element occurs 10 times, it steps down and updates the map values over 10 loop iterations (with 5 map operations per loop) from 10, to 9... down to 0.

Comment: Setting the hasmap size is just a microoptimization. It stops the hashmap from rehashing in the middle of the algorithm slowing things down.

Hmm.. as for the innermost loop that is interesting. If I have time I'll think about that.

Comment: @Funk show me a counterexample that won't work. I haven't found any invalid counter examples and leetcode.com couldn't either.

The ratio 2 is only assumed for analysis. It isn't a requirement for the algorithm to work.

Comment: @AminM You're right, must have dropped the ball while reading your code.

Comment: Assuming this solution is correct, can we say it is worst case `O(n)` due to the use of hashmaps? Is there an obvious way to avoid the use of hashmaps and achieve the `O(n)` worst-case bound instead of an expected runtime bound?

Comment: @ldog well the only way to try break the O(n) case with the hashmap would be to have a bunch of repeated values.  But since we are counting frequencies that would still work fine.

If you had a case where you could somehow include values that always had the same hash code.. I guess it is possible but extremely improbable. And it would probably depend on the size of the Hash table as well so it could be easily solved.

So for all intents an purposes this is worst case O(n).

Comment: @AminM: okay, there is a trivial solution to this problem without this much complexity by sorting the array first. Since leetcode specifies `0 <= changed[i] <= 10^5` sorting can be implemented in `O(n)`, yielding a definitely `O(n)` algorithm. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: @ldog please reread the problem here in Stack Overflow. There is no specified range of numbers. Just that it be O(n). This is not leetcode.

In general Radix Sort will be O(N log E) where E is the maximum range.

Answer (score 1):

```
def findOriginalArray(self, changed: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    size = len(changed)
    ans = []
    left_elements = size//2
    
    #IF SIZE IS ODD THEN RETURN [] NO SOLN. IS POSSIBLE
    if(size%2 !=0):
        return ans
    
    #FREQUENCY DICTIONARY given array [0,0,2,1] my map will be: {0:2,2:1,1:1}
    d = {}
    for i in changed:
        if(i in d):
            d[i]+=1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
            
    # CHECK THE EDGE CASE OF 0         
    if(0 in d):
        count = d[0]
        half = count//2
        if((count % 2 != 0) or (half > left_elements)):
            return ans
        left_elements -= half
        ans = [0 for i in range(half)] 
        
    #CHECK REST OF THE CASES : considering the values will be 10^5
    for i in range(1,50001):
        if(i in d):
            if(d[i] > 0):
                count = d[i]
                if(count > left_elements):
                    ans = []
                    break
                left_elements -= d[i]
                for j in range(count):
                    ans.append(i)
                if(2*i in d):
                    if(d[2*i] < count):
                        ans = []
                        break
                    else:
                        d[2*i] -= count
                else:
                    ans = []
                    break
    return ans
```

Comment: thanks @kcsquared for pointing out 0 condition. ...  I have submitted this soln on leetcode it worked

Comment: It's not a good/clean soln but it's a correct soln

Comment: This solution does work, and may have been what OP wanted as an O(n) solution. However it does assume that the max number is less than 100000 (or linear in `n` more generally) since it's doing a counting sort. There is in fact a hash-map based `O(n)` solution that works with exponentially large numbers.

Comment: @kcsquared if value is larger than 10^5 then we have to store in sorted order. To do this either we have to use treemap(nlogn) or otherwise sort the array(nlogn). can you please share the approach alone using hashmap? {Maybe i am wrong for larger case} .... Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, it was on the [Leetcode discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-original-array-from-doubled-array/discuss/1485450/Python-hashmap-O(n)-solution.-NO-Sorting!) forum for this question. I was surprised it existed as well, and might write an answer based on it if I think I can add to it.

Comment: @kcsquared sure thanks .. counter is same as multiset in C++ ..  but multiset is build upon trees.. hmm strange for me too. please include the base data structure of counter/multiset in that ans. it will be helpful. thanks in adv.

Comment: Counter is actually closer to unordered_map; it's actually just a plain Python dictionary which only allows ints as values and has some syntactic sugar that's useful if you're storing counts. Like `c = Counter(arr)` is implemented roughly as `c = {}; for x in arr: c[x] = c.get(x,0) + 1`, so doing the same work as your for loop initializing `d`

Comment: @kcsquared sorry for asking multiple questions ..... My last que still not understood how it is maintaining the order? (like sorted order)

Comment: strictly speaking if you simulate a Radix sort (or something that is based on the # of bits of the numbers) you aren't really O(N) you are O(N log M) where M is the max possible number and log M is the number of bits.

Comment: @AminM I haven't understood this comment is for whom? (Means its regarding my soln  or telling some information) ... If it's regarding my soln. Kindly share the lines where you found its more than O(n).. I will be thankful

Comment: the number 10^5 is not really a constant..  it's a hidden dependency on the number of bits in the number. Radix sort is not really O(N) either.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple idea which might not be the best, but I could not think of a case where it would not work. Having the array `A` with the doubled elements and randomly shuffled, keep a helper map. Process each element of the array and, each time you find a new element, add it to the map with the value 0. When an element is processed, increment `map[i]` and decrement `map[2*i]`. Next you iterate over the map and print the elements that have a value greater than zero.

A simple example, say that the vector is:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

And the doubled/shuffled version is:

```
A = [3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6]
```

When processing 3, first add the keys 3 and 6 to the map with value zero. Increment `map[3]` and decrement `map[6]`. This way, `map[3] = 1` and `map[6] = -1`. Then for the next element `map[2] = 1` and `map[4] = -1` and so forth. The final state of the map in this example would be `map[1] = 1`, `map[2] = 1`, `map[3] = 1`, `map[4] = -1`, `map[6] = 0`, `map[8] = -1`, `map[12] = -1`.

Then you just process the keys of the map and, for each key with a value greater than zero, add it to the output. There are certainly more efficient solutions, but this one is `O(n)`.

Comment: Small logic addition:  odd value will always be the part of original array. Also considering one time only we will perform the double command. So my original arr will be size/2... For even : smallest ( size - total odd values will be part) .. now counter hashmap your approach will work or make the frequency array

Comment: Does this work for `[1,3,4,2,6,8]`, whose original array is `[1,3,4]`? It seems like `4` would have a value of `0` in the map. Also, this doesn't account for zeros, or elements appearing more than once

Comment: Lil update In my case make frequency array 0 to max value in the array .... So as per @kcsquared test case my frequency array will look like this [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1] ... Now I know only 1 more double will be there run loop size = 3 ... We found original array=  [1] , size will be 2 , update the arr[2*I] -= 1 then move forward until size =0 ... this will be O(2*n). To reduce the multiplier 2 just use hash map.

Comment: @adarsh I'm not sure I follow the computations. Could you possibly add some pseudocode or code? As far as I can tell, the original algorithm of the post fails on the testcase I mentioned. I don't believe an `O(N)` solution is known without extra assumptions about the range.

Comment: hi @kcsquared just submitted the code it worked fine used the hashmap approach.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can try this.
With time is `O(N + KlogK)` where `N` is the length of `input`, and `K` is the number of unique elements in `input`.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> findOriginalArray(vector<int>& input) {
        if (input.size() % 2) return {};
        unordered_map<int, int> m;
        for (int n : input) m[n]++;
        vector<int> nums;
        for (auto [n, cnt] : m) nums.push_back(n);
        sort(begin(nums), end(nums));
        vector<int> out;
        for (int n : nums) {
            if (m[2 * n] < m[n]) return {};
            for (int i = 0; i < m[n]; ++i, --m[2 * n]) out.push_back(n);
        }
        return out;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear about the space complexity required in the question, so this is my top-of-the-mind attempt to this question if this requires O(n) time complexity.

1. If the length of the input array is not even, then its wrong !!
2. Create a map, add the elements of the input array to it.
3. Divide each element in the input array by 2 and check if that value exists in the map. If it exists, add it to the array (slice) orig.
4. There is a chance we have added duplicate values to this original array, clean it!!

Here is a sample go code:
https://go.dev/play/p/w4mm-rloHyi

I am sure we can optimize this code in a lot of ways for space complexities. But its O(n) time complexity.